Building the tensor product of multiple algebras in sage?
I want to build $\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$ in Sage, where $\Lambda$ is the algebra of symmetric functions. You can build the algebra of symmetric functions in the Schur bases with SymmetricFunctions(QQ).schur(), but I am unsure how to take the tensor product of this with itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Edit: I also need to build $\Lambda\otimes\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$.
Edit 2: The following seem to give the same functionality. Was it even neccesary to build $\Lambda\otimes\Lambda\otimes\Lambda$?
s = SymmetricFunctions(QQ).schur()
S.<t> = tensor((s, s, s))['t']

vs
s = SymmetricFunctions(QQ).schur()
S.<t> = PolynomialRing(QQ)

